# Should my question on stackoverflow be migrated here rather than closed?

Tags: support

I asked a question on stackoverflow about password strength and it got closed as non-constructive, but I actually did learn stuff from the answers. I was advised to post here to see whether the question sould be migrated here rather than closed. Any opinions?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435338/doesnt-impose-a-minimum-password-length-make-the-password-weaker-by-reducing-the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely.
Though it shouldnt have been closed there as not constructive, it should have been closed as off-topic - it's not a programming question, but it *definitely* belongs here.
By the by, "not constructive" is really questionable - it's definitely constructive, and its also not a question of being subjective: this is a clear cut, mathematical answer.

Comment: Agreed.  This question is perfectly on-topic here.  There are many security-related questions on Stack Overflow that would probably get better answers here ... but so it goes.